# How do I use the AVFoundation framework to take a picture with the iPhone camera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession, ios-camera

I need the iOS camera to take a picture without any input from the user. How would I go about doing this? This is my code so far:

```
-(void)initCapture{
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *newVideoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] init];

    AVCaptureStillImageOutput *newStillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                nil];


    [newStillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];


    AVCaptureSession *newCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    if ([newCaptureSession canAddInput:newVideoInput]) {
        [newCaptureSession addInput:newVideoInput];
    }
    if ([newCaptureSession canAddOutput:newStillImageOutput]) {
        [newCaptureSession addOutput:newStillImageOutput];
    }
    self.stillImageOutput = newStillImageOutput;
}
```

What else do I need to add and where do I go from here? I don't want to take a video, only a single still image. Also, how would I convert the image into a UIImage afterwards? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [this tutorial](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/), you should be able to do this:

```
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation: newStillImageOutput];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

And there's your UIImage object!

Comment: is there any third party framework for taking picture from device.

Comment: that's a separate question @karthikeyan; ask it in a new one (and explain in that new question why you would want to avoid the AVFoundation frameworks)